# pip gets installed to wrong directory when upgrading

Tags: python, pip, continuous-integration, python-wheel

In a CI runner, I update pip and wheel to their latest versions by executing `python -m pip install --upgrade pip wheel`.

This seems to result in the pip module being installed to a subdirectory of the current working directory:

```
WARNING: The scripts pip, pip3 and pip3.9 are installed in '/opt/trelby/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
```

This leads to the following problem:

```
Successfully installed pip-23.2.1 wheel-0.41.2
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.18/x64/bin/python: No module named pip.__main__; 'pip' is a package and cannot be directly executed
```

Python has been installed via https://github.com/actions/setup-python. The issue only occurs for Python 3.8 and 3.9, not for Python 3.10 and 3.11.

This is the full log of the CI: https://github.com/limburgher/trelby/actions/runs/6212268094/job/16862236433?pr=80